# Moving a SharePoint Licence to another farm

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, licensing, service-pack-2

I have currently got a SharePoint 2010 RTM environment, 1 App Server 1 SQL. However i need to move the farm out of where it is hosted, so i have decided to build a new farm from scratch on a new server move content dbs etc and then remove the old servers. The new server will be Windows 2012 R2 so will need a SharePoint 2010 SP2 install. I am wondering if i'd be able to use the same licence etc for this or would i need to get another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my understanding, yes you can use the same licensing as long as you decommissioned or uninstall the SharePoint completely on the old servers.

SharePoint licensing is for the Version ( i.e. SP 2010, SP 2013 or SP 2016 etc), that mean if you bought the license for SharePoint 2010 it will cover untill last update of SharePoint 2010 (unless MSFT say soemthing).